# Missing files in android build for multi device hybrid apps

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am attempting to debug my application on my android device. running 4.1.2

The app builds and installs correctly but nothing displayed. I get an error message in the debugger that WinJS is undefined. so I check to make sure everything is referenced. and it appears all my scripts and files are not being added to the app package. This only happens when debugging on the android device the app runs fine on the ripple emulator and for windows phone device and windows store.

I have made sure the build tools revision 19 and all drivers are installed.

Please assist

Comment: How are you adding WinJS references to your project? Are you saying none of your project resources are being added to the app package?

Comment: I add the framework min files to a folder scripts/frameworks, then reference them in my index.html

Comment: please post the output log from VS